# overflow-x scrolling with display: flex, last child item not showing parent div padding and margin

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at the last item, parent div padding not working here. Any help?

**Here is my code:**

```css
.horizontal-scrollable {
  padding: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hide;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.year-tag {
  background: #E6E7E8;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 375px;font-family: sans-serif;background:red;">
  <div class="horizontal-scrollable year-list">
    <a class="year-tag">2020</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2019</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2018</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2017</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2016</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2015</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2014</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2013</a>
    <a class="year-tag">See More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: None of your `year-tag` elements are showing parent div padding. You can check the computed styles to verify.

Comment: @CodeIt `.horizontal-scrollable` div's padding: 15px; is working for the child elements except right side.. also there is a margin-right for `year-tag`.. both are not working at the moment.

Comment: @vishu Parent element padding doesn't affect the padding of your child elements. `margin-right` on your last child element has no effect because of the `overflow-x` in your parent div. If you need a margin at the end, you may add `margin-right` to parent div.

Comment: @CodeIt `margin-right` for parent div is not working

Comment: See this, https://jsfiddle.net/v5aeywu7/

Comment: @CodeIt but I need tag ending like this: [https://imgur.com/HrkPBHP](https://imgur.com/HrkPBHP) not need a space at ending: [https://imgur.com/c92zYOQ](https://imgur.com/c92zYOQ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `inline-flex`.

```css
.wrapper-div {
  width: 375px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: red;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.horizontal-scrollable {
  padding: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hide;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.year-tag {
  background: #E6E7E8;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-div">
  <div class="horizontal-scrollable year-list">
    <a class="year-tag">2020</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2019</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2018</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2017</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2016</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2015</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2014</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2013</a>
    <a class="year-tag">See More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a dummy div with `opacity: 0` to solve this.

```css
.horizontal-scrollable {
  padding: 15px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hide;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.year-tag {
  background: #E6E7E8;
  padding: 12px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 14px;
  border: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 375px;font-family: sans-serif;background:red;">
  <div class="horizontal-scrollable year-list">
    <a class="year-tag">2020</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2019</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2018</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2017</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2016</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2015</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2014</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2013</a>
    <a class="year-tag">See More</a>
    <div class="year-tag" style="opacity: 0; padding: 4px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> This is not the most elegant solution to fix the problem. You may also check the answer posted by @soothran.

Comment: I appreciate your support.. Great !

Comment: @vishnu I don't have any experience working with flex, that's why i was not able to come up with *flex* based solution. Thanks for appreciating my efforts.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by adding a pseudo element to the end of the list.

```
.horizontal-scrollable:after {
  content:'';
  width: 8px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`display: inline-flex;` still produces (almost) the same result. Try `display:block;` + `display inline-block;` approach to solve this. Something like this.

```css
.horizontal-scrollable {
 padding: 15px;
 white-space: nowrap;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 overflow-y: hide;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 scrollbar-width: none;
 display: inline-flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 width: 100%;
}

.year-tag {
 background: #E6E7E8;
 padding: 12px;
 font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 14px;
 border: 0;
 font-weight: bold;
 border-radius: 3px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 8px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
 flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 375px;font-family: sans-serif;background:red;">
  <div class="horizontal-scrollable year-list">
    <a class="year-tag">2020</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2019</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2018</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2017</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2016</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2015</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2014</a>
    <a class="year-tag">2013</a>
    <a class="year-tag">See More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```